# django rest framework not showing response data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i have a problem with django rest framework and mySql the response data not showing:
i define serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..models import H010002

class H010002Serializer(serializers.Serializer):
  class Meta:
    model       = H010002


    # Note: any fild passed her will send to xhr request
    fields      = [
        'id',
        'module_name',
        'module_description',
        'module_type',
    ]
```

2- view.py

```
from .serializers import H010002Serializer
from ..models import H010002
from rest_framework.generics import (
 ListAPIView,
 RetrieveAPIView,
)

# Create your views here.
class H010002ListAPIView(ListAPIView):
 queryset            = H010002.objects.all()
 serializer_class    = H010002Serializer
```

3- data base included 1 record
[image]

4- django rest framework disply empty data with status 200 OK

[image]

Note: if i use normal class ListView the data come correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [**`serializers.ModelSerializer`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) class to create the serializer.

```
class H010002Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = H010002
        fields = ['id', 'module_name', 'module_description', 'module_type', ]
```

Comment: Glad that worked!! Would you mind upvoting the answer?